# Modifying the model with class method when creating the instance in Django?

Tags: django

I have a model which represents bought adverts:

```
class Bought(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    advert = models.ForeignKey(Advert, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
```

The adverts may expire or the quantity has been sold out and in this moment the Advert instance is being deleted (signals) and the mirror-reflection instance of AdvertArchives is being created. In this moment the Bought instance of Advert is being deleted because of models.CASCADE. Before it happens, using the same signal, I want to recreate the Bought instance but to do it I need to change the advert attribute's ForeignKey to AdvertArchive. Is there any way to accomplish this via simple @classmethod ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution instead of having to create an extra table called `AdvertArchive` and duplicating an existing `Advert` would be to put a boolean field `archived` on the `Advert` model. This way, you can keep your ForeignKey the same, and just update the `Advert` to set `archived` to True. You can then filter archived vs non-archived via `Advert.objects.filter(archived=True)` and `Advert.objects.filter(archived=False)` respectively.

Comment: Just read your comment. I came up with exactly the same idea and implemented it :) Way more easier and less complicated. Thanks though !